# How do I ensure that logs are retained forever in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to configure Kafka *never* to delete logs.  Looking at their documentation, I see two kinds of parameters that control this:

- The "log cleaner", described at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction.  It seems that setting `log.cleaner.enable = false` prevents the cleaner from deleting or compacting logs.
- The "log retention" mechanism, described at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#configuration under `log.retention.<time scales>`.  It seems that setting `log.retention.ms = -1` signals infinite retention.

My question is:

> What is the relationship between these two mechanisms, are these the only two, and are the above settings necessary and sufficient to prevent logs from ever being deleted?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure which version you are using. For me, I use this:

```
log.retention.hours=2147483647
```

That's roughly 245,000 years. I believe I tried `-1` at some point, but using the max value worked. Perhaps `log.retention.ms` accepts different values, but regardless -- the second of your configuration options should be sufficient. My guess is neither option is necessary; either would be sufficient. Certainly, the second one is sufficient by itself.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39735773/7571412) answer, you can set -1 for `log.retention.hours` and `log.retention.bytes`.