# Make Kafka Topic Log Retention Permanent

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am writing log messages into a Kafka Topic and I want the retention of this topic to be permanent. I have seen in Kafka and Kafka Connect (_schemas, connect-configs, connect-status, connect-offsets, etc) that there are special topics that are not deleted by the log retention time. How do I enforce a topic to be like these other special topics? Is it the naming convention or some other properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These special topics are compacted topics. This means they are made up of keyed messages and only keep the list recent key. A full write [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction). This is probably what you want for infinite retention time in most cases.

Comment: How to retain data for only one topic(keep the data forever) ? log.retention.bytes and log.retention.ms are applicable to all topics, but not to only a single topic.

Comment: Example of per-topic config at https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-message-retention

Answer (score 45):

If you want to retain all topics forever, you can set both `log.retention.hours` and `log.retention.bytes` to -1.

Comment: It appears that prior to April 2015 the way to do this was to set `log.retention.hours` to `2147483647`. Then a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1990) added the -1 feature. That JIRA, however, did not explicitly state what value is interpreted as "retain forever". I dug around the code a little and indeed, it's [-1](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaConfig.scala#L1165). You can also set -1 for [hours, minutes or ms](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaConfig.scala#L1078-L1090)

Comment: Is there any reason why we shouldn't do this other than too much space used?  Like is there a scalability or speed issue as apart of this?

Comment: something worth noting is the limitation is space per partition, and each partition is limited to the size of a disk. indirectly, that may impact scalability but other than that I don't think there is anything.

Comment: Are you sure log.retention.hours work? Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70535714/4106031

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default values for parameters here:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-properties.html

`log.retention.bytes` and `log.retention.ms` can be set to -1 if you want to keep the data in topics forever.

Comment: How to retain data for only one topic(keep the data forever) ? log.retention.bytes and log.retention.ms are applicable to all topics, but not to any single topic.

Comment: Does not log.retention.hours=-1 work?