# Kafka data got compacted/deleted not respecting the configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using **Strimzi** to manage our Kafka cluster in Kubernetes.

Below is our Strimzi configuration for our Kafka cluster (removed the SSL and authorization confs below):

```
[kafka@k8s-kafka-2 kafka]$ cat /tmp/strimzi.properties
##########
# User provided configuration
##########
log.message.format.version=2.6
log.retention.hours=-1
offsets.retention.minutes=525600
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
```

We are using Infinite log retention to never delete data from our Kafka topics.
We also have a default cleanup policy (which is delete and not compact)

Today, our topics oldest offset moved from 0 to high numbers. We lost a lot of earlier messages due to this.

We are trying to figure out why it happened when we are using infinite retention (log.retention.hours=-1).

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if adding which details can help you help me.

Why could Kafka compact the topics or move its offset from 0 to higher numbers when the retention is infinite?

Answer (score 0):

In kafka documentation the valid values for the log.retention.* broker parameters are not reported. the only reference to the -1 value is for log.retention.ms. I suggest to use log.retention.ms=-1 instead of log.retention.hours=-1.

Comment: Thanks Saxon. I will try to look into code of Kafka to see log.retention.hours take effect or not.

Comment: Basically I wanted to know what exactly caused it so that we can prevent it from repeating.

Comment: This is the delete segment code. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/22d056c9b76c9bf8417d8701594d1fcee1c6a655/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/UnifiedLog.scala#L1373-L1381

Comment: Please check this code -1 will work for both hours and minutes retention as well https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaConfig.scala#L1606-L1619. Test case to prove that https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/3139cc31f6cab26f3dfd429c36280d1567dbf61a#diff-f4b04bc51f23ea749861aecc07d402ce0dd160551bb7af8b772f6dd9b5f8e729R94-R96

Comment: I don't know scala, but if kafka version is 2.6 the retention functionality seems properly implemented for log.retention.hours as well. Did'you check if some topic retention parameter overrides the broker ones? May be it was the first thing you did.

Comment: Found that it is still happening, oldest topic offsets are still moving ahead. Also found in the log, kafka is actually deleting them due to `due to retention time 604800000ms breach`

Comment: I am not understanding why is Kafka using 7days retention when we specified log.retention.hours=-1 (infinite). We will use retention.ms in future to be safe, but we need to understand the cause to be really safe for future.

Comment: Created one more issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554769/kafka-ate-my-data-with-correct-configuration?noredirect=1#comment124721993_70554769

Comment: Created a bug in Kafka https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13575