# Kafka ate my data with correct configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

I have infinite retention set in Kafka, the deletion policy is `delete`, still Kafka went ahead and deleted my data.

Kafka version: 2.6

Topic Configuration:

```
  retention.ms=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  retention.bytes=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.bytes=-1}
  delete.retention.ms=86400000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000}
```

Broker Configurations(3 brokers)

```
broker0.conf:  log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000}
broker0.conf:  log.retention.hours=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:log.retention.hours=-1, DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.hours=168}
broker0.conf:  log.retention.minutes=null sensitive=false synonyms={}
broker0.conf:  offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000}
broker0.conf:  log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000}
broker0.conf:  log.retention.ms=null sensitive=false synonyms={}
broker0.conf:  log.retention.bytes=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.bytes=-1}
broker0.conf:  offsets.retention.minutes=525600 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:offsets.retention.minutes=525600, DEFAULT_CONFIG:offsets.retention.minutes=10080}
broker1.conf:  log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000}
broker1.conf:  log.retention.hours=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:log.retention.hours=-1, DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.hours=168}
broker1.conf:  log.retention.minutes=null sensitive=false synonyms={}
broker1.conf:  offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000}
broker1.conf:  log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000}
broker1.conf:  log.retention.ms=null sensitive=false synonyms={}
broker1.conf:  log.retention.bytes=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.bytes=-1}
broker1.conf:  offsets.retention.minutes=525600 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:offsets.retention.minutes=525600, DEFAULT_CONFIG:offsets.retention.minutes=10080}
broker2.conf:  log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000}
broker2.conf:  log.retention.hours=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:log.retention.hours=-1, DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.hours=168}
broker2.conf:  log.retention.minutes=null sensitive=false synonyms={}
broker2.conf:  offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000}
broker2.conf:  log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000}
broker2.conf:  log.retention.ms=null sensitive=false synonyms={}
broker2.conf:  log.retention.bytes=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.bytes=-1}
broker2.conf:  offsets.retention.minutes=525600 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:offsets.retention.minutes=525600, DEFAULT_CONFIG:offsets.retention.minutes=10080}
```

These configurations were taken out using the Kafka distribution's `kafka-config.sh` script. The below picture shows the oldest offset increasing for all the topics on 21st December 2021. For 8 long months there was no change in the oldest_offset(i.e. not data was deleted from the time we created the cluster).

[image]

Please suggest do you see any reason for Kafka to delete my data with this configuration in place. It happened to each and every topic in the cluster.

Kafka has the following logs for deletion:

```
2021-12-21 15:28:25,337 INFO [Log partition=loader-09779e-ts.titan.users-0, dir=/var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log2] Found deletable segments with base offsets [0,5413,6753,8093,9438,10782,12124,13469,14813,16156,17499,18836,19785,21128,22471,23175,23684,25023,25603,26512,27165,28257,29600,30928,32270,33604,34930,36274,37619,38963] due to retention time 604800000ms breach (kafka.log.Log) [kafka-scheduler-2]
```

**due to retention time 604800000ms breach**

How is Kafka using 604800000ms when we have specified infinite retention and also querying the information shows -1 as retention.

This looks like a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: _had 3TB storage and we hit that number_ - what does this mean? You filled the disks because you had infinite retention?

Comment: I just found out it is still happening. Just edited the question. Somehow the kafka is taking default 7days retention instead of infinite -1. See: 2022-01-02 08:53:18,124 INFO [Log partition=ts.praccomm.patientsms-0, dir=/var/lib/kafka/data/kafka-log2] Found deletable segments with base offsets [380475915] due to retention time 604800000ms breach (kafka.log.Log) [kafka-scheduler-7]            But the topic and broker shows log.retention.hours=-1

Comment: @OneCricketeer no we need to reprocess all the events sometimes so we keep all data in Kafka and never delete it. The storage I am talking is the total volume/disk size we have given to it. It was 2TB and we increased to 3TB. But that is unrelated now due to ^

Comment: Need some help in finding out why Kafka is using 7d retention when topic and broker configuration is showing infinite(-1) retention as set

Comment: Also, why aren't you only setting the ms retention? Why set hours and minutes?

Comment: Yes, because they are valid configurations: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaConfig.scala#L1606-L1619. In future clusters we will us retention.ms to be safe, but are doing a RCA to be really sure why it happened and why retention.hours is not working

Comment: Yeah, that code block seems fine. You could try setting log cleaner threads to zero and even disabling that, but I think that's meant for compacting

Comment: Created a bug in Kafka https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13575

Comment: Regarding your use case... Do you really need all the data? Does this data have keys that could be compacted?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes in future clusters we are going to use compacted cleanup policy for sure. We only care about the latest event. But we are keeping this cluster as is until we are certain what went wrong, creating a new cluster for Kafka with that.

Comment: So, do you have no compacted topics at all, then? Or those were also wiped? If so, then yeah, that seems like a problem. Regarding finding the problem, don't rely on the Kafka configs script. You might want to poke around in the actual topic configurations that are stored in each Zookeeper