# maximum message retention in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

what is the maximum message retention period for a given topic? 
I'm running a local setup and based on what I see, max retention seems to be 4 weeks. Is this something that can be adjusted to a larger retention period ?

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum is forever

You can disable retention by setting `log.retention.ms=-1`, however that might not be exposed in the UI

Related [How do I ensure that logs are retained forever in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449478/how-do-i-ensure-that-logs-are-retained-forever-in-kafka)